# How is possible to get cursor position and cursor events outside and cross origin iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, dom-events

I am working on a video player. This player is used inside an iframe on the client's page, so it is cross-origin. When the user clicks on seekbar and drags the cursor out of iframe, I can't identify the mouseup event, so it keeps selected. I notice that youtube player can do it, and can identify cursor events outside iframe. How can i do it using javascript?

Comment: I am not sure your issue is because of the crossorigin iframe. I just did a small test where I hosted a page on netlify and embedded it in an iframe on a local dev server and I was able to click, then while holding down the mouse button move it outside of the frame, release, and act on that mouseup event. Can you post your event handling code?

Comment: There is a way to solve this issue, using the document.parent and adding the eventListener there, but it doesn't work in crossorigin. The following code is an example of code that doesn't work if the mousedown starts inside iframe and the mouseup occurs out of iframe.
`document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
     console.log(e);
  });
`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that the mouseup event only fires if the pointer is directly over the element with the eventListener. It doesn't keep track of what element the mousedown event fired on, it only knows about the state of the mouse at the time of the mouseup.

> The mouseup event is fired at an Element when a button on a pointing
>   device (such as a mouse or trackpad) is released while the pointer is
>   located inside it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event

Therefore you need some other method of tracking if your user has initiated the drag on your seekbar playhead.

A possible solution is to use a boolean variable. Then to listen to mouseup on `document` and check the value of that variable.

```
let scrubbingTimeline = false;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mousedown', ()=> {
    console.log('Mouse down')
    scrubbingTimeline = true
})
document.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=> {
    if(scrubbingTimeline === true) {
        console.log('Mouse has been released')
        scrubbingTimeline = false
    }
})
```

Another possible solution would be to initiate the mouseup listener only once the mousedown callback has fired. Then to stop listening after one event. Like this:

```
function mouseUpHandler() {
    console.log("Mouse Lifted")
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mousedown', ()=> {
    console.log('Down')
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
})
```

**Important: This code is for the inner document. I.E. the one that will *be* the iframe.**

Comment: The asker is the one who is creating the document which will be the iframe. It will work fine, since he has control over the inner document in the situation. In other words he IS the 3rd party.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When the cursor leaves the iframe, it loses all mouse events, so it stops listening to the mouseup event.

Comment: Interesting. The tests I have run, with the inner and outer document on different servers and domains do work for me on windows Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. Can you go here and see if the console statements happen when you mousedown on the button and mouseup somewhere outside of the iframe. https://nervous-thompson-3a952a.netlify.com/